Which spells changed between the 2014 and 2024 edition of 5e?
In browsing through the new D&D 5e 2024 rules, I already saw several spells that have changes to how they function, for example counterspell has been rewritten (and, as far as I can tell, nerfed), wish has been rewritten, the ruby dust required for forcecage now is consumed, polymorph effects now give temporary hit points instead of providing a new set of hit points, the various conjure spells now do not summon up to eight creatures any more, but work more like guardian spirits, there are new summon spells instead that summon a single creature of a given type (fiend, elemental, fey etc.).
There also are a few spells that graduated from supplements into the core rules, like steel wind strike or toll the dead. And there are changes to the spellcasting rules, for example that you now can fail a saving throw if you so please, or some spells create "emanations". I'm not interested in those here. I'd just like to know all the spells where the spell changed functionally in a clearly obvious way.

It’s not clear exactly what you’re asking for here. Every spell changed, because the base rules changed, and every spell changed in that the text of the description changed. It seems like neither of these are what you’re looking for, but I’m not sure what you are looking for. Voting to close for needs details - we need a better understanding of what constitutes a change for the purposes of your question.

(Unless you consider “every spell changed” to be the correct answer to your question, in which case I’ll post that and retract my close vote.)

@ThomasMarkov I'm not looking for all spells. What I mean is, for example Invisibility or blur have not functionally changed, even though the way it is worded has changed slightly. I can see that it will be hard to draw a clear line however, between "has not changed at all" (same text) and "has changed materially", like wish, as you need to define then what amount of change counts as different. Maybe there is no good way to reasonably do that on this site, and I'll just have to wait for someone on a forum doing the work, or do it myself eventually.

This is going to be quite an exhaustive list and as such might be off-topic here.

@NobodytheHobgoblin The most practical advice here is probably something like “It’s a new game, so it’s probably best to assume that it isn’t the same as the old game.”

Re counterspell being nerfed(?): I recommend checking out the answer here.

Next question: What rules have changed from 2014 to 2024? o_O Sorry, but you get my gist. :) ... I'm not sure how this question is meant to help you or anyone else?

@Senmurv Yes, that was another question I have, not the classes but the non-class rules that changed, but thankfully, that is also covered in the linked post, so I don’t have to ask that question. I think that is a pretty practical thing one would want to know when switching over - not how some nomenclature changed or such, but what rules now work different, like initiative.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Most people would probably work that out by just reading the rules themselves rather than asking other people to write executive summaries for free.

A better approach here would be to just play the game, and when you actually have trouble or confusion at the table of play about a rule that changed, ask about that so you can explain the context of the confusion and we can give you a good, concrete answer. This approach has always been the best way to ask questions on this site, and that isn’t going to change.

The scope of this question is the problem with it.  Narrow down the scope a bit and the chances of an answer increases.  Also, play and find out.  Ask questions as they arise.

The intent of the question seems very obvious to me:  "I have years of experience and knowledge with 5e spells, and it would be really convenient to have a lookup table telling me when I have to check the book because something changed."

It's a perfectly cromulent question.

I didn’t vote to close, nor will I vote to reopen. However, if people want this question, then the answers need to contain the answer within our format at our site. A link to somewhere else is just a shopping question for where to find this, not the actual answer. So if someone wants to do the work, let them, but don’t let people put up answers that don’t actually answer the whole question here.

@Novak I agree, however, my initial criticism still stands: OP hasn’t clearly explained what counts as a change for the purposes of this question. There is more than one meaningful sense in which all spells have changed, but that isn’t what Groody is looking for, and unfortunately, I don’t think he’s explained what he is looking for.

I think experts are capable of determining what constitutes an obvious functional change.

I don't believe this is a shopping list question, either.  Not all lists are shopping lists.

@SeriousBri It's not a fixed list; as more 5e-2024 books get published, the list will grow.

@ObliviousSage Either way, the answers we have now are link only answers.

@ObliviousSage the 2014 list is fixed, doesn't matter what is released in 2024

@SeriousBri Spells published in the 2014 edition but not yet published in the 2024 edition could be published later on.

@ObliviousSage yes but the spells published in 2014 are still a limit, it might change a bit, but only up to a limit. So my point is that it isn't a huge list to the point of being difficult to answer or undergoing drastic changes at any point.

An exhaustive list of significant changes is a big task, but attempts are being made to compile them.
The longest one I’ve found is the Spells section of RPGbot’s DnD 5e to DnD 2024 Transition Guide. It’s divided into removed spells, altered spells (with a focus on functional changes), and new spells.
I haven’t reproduced it here since it’s still a work in progress, but the list of altered spells included about 185 entries. The changes range from minor (e.g. Antilife Shell has some clarifications but is more or less the same; Banishing Smite has changed schools from Abjuration to Conjuration) to major (e.g. Cloud of Daggers can now be moved around) and massive (e.g. “complete rewrites” of spells like Conjure Celestial and Sleep). The change descriptions for spells I’m familiar with seem accurate, though note that the site has an “optimisation” focus that flavours some of the commentary.
In case the original link becomes inaccessible, here’s an archived version from 4 October 2024 (thanks to TylerW).

You may want to post the answers to avoid link rot. Also, RPGbot doesn't include the changes to Shocking Grasp.

@nonymous The guide says it is not yet complete, so I don't think it would be worth copying here right now.

This is very helpful, thank you. I will wait a bit with checkmarking, to see if someone can come up with a complete list, but this solves the bulk of what I was looking for.

I thought about copying it, but yes, it’s incomplete and still very long. It also includes spells with only minimal changes so to keep it entirely on topic I’d need to go through and edit it. I’ll revise this answer to indicate that and will revisit should it be marked as a completed list. Thanks for the archive link, @TylerW!

This is a link-only answer, which we don't generally allow. If you can't make it stand on its own without the link, then maybe the question isn't really answerable in the SE format.

@ObliviousSage that’s fair. It’s not that I can’t make this answer stand on its own, more that it would take considerable work going through lists like the one linked and checking them against the primary sources to make sure they’re correct. I haven’t had time for that, but I figured this resource ought to be available. Do we have a policy on those sort of circumstances - where a question is arduous to answer, but an external resource exists where it’s been done? Or questions that require an exhaustive list to answer?

Usually that's a sign that such a question should be closed.

You say, "I'd just like to know all the spells where the spell changed functionally in a clearly obvious way."
Your mileage may vary, but the Spells list in D&D Beyond marks spells as Legacy, so you can easily see the old definition and the new definition next to each other.
There are some oddities.  For instance, the first page shows Acid Arrow [Legacy], with no new Acid Arrow, however, Melf's Acid Arrow exists in both legacy and updated forms.
The list can be filtered for "Legacy (includes 2014 rules)", which will show you the spells that have been superseded.
My list shows 20 pages of legacy spells, at 20 spells a page, so about 400 spells have been marked Legacy, so about 400 spells have either been changed or dropped.

I'm not sure this is correct. I don't think any spells have been removed. JC's explanation of backward compatibility is "Same with [...] any other element that basically as soon as it appears in its new form, that new form replaces the old form." That quote doesn't specifically mention spells, so it's not clear, but it's possible that the "legacy" Acid Arrow is still considered the current version of the spell.

Acid Arrow discontinued?! Does Melf know??

Yeah, I screwed up the acid arrow thing.  Corrected.

They’ve dropped the “no IP names” versions of spells from the free rules for 2024, I think, which probably makes this counting method a bit unreliable.

@GuybrushMcKenzie In terms of a perfect count, yeah, a little more work would be needed.  For the majority of spells, though, it's a quick way to see what's changed.  You just have to know that named spells are a bit different.

WotC's official list of Redesigned and Revised Spells
I found a post by Wizards titeled Updates in the Player's Handbook 2024, that lists the differences between the 2014 and the 2024 version. Among other things, under the "Spells" heading linked here, Wizards list two levels of altered Spells, Redesigned and Revised.
There is no further explanation of what the terms mean. It appears "redesigned" may include rewrites where the way the spell works has fundamentally changed, for example, conjure celestial now does not summon an actual celestial creature, but a spirit that manifests as a cylinder of light that harms or heals creatures within.
As far as I can tell, Revised means usually lighter changes than Redesigned, for example light still works very similar to how it did before (20 foot range bright, 20 foot dim, can choose color, ends if cast again, touch, on an object that is not too large etc., with the minor difference that it just does not work on objects worn or carried rather than giving the creature a Dex save so it does not work). But some have more substantial changes, like wish that now allows you to switch feats on a creature.
Spells not on either list appear to be considered unchanged by Wizards, because they do not appear in this post about edition changes, even if the wording changed between editions, like for example for invisibility.
So if you are used to the 2014 spells and want to know where you have to be careful something now works differently, take a close look at the Redesigned spells to understand what they do now, and check on the differences of the Revised spells.
Redesigned Spells
Here is the list of all the "redesigned" spells (with level):

0 Blade Ward
0 Chill Touch
0 Friends
0 Guidance
0 Resistance
0 True Strike
1 Chromatic Orb
1 Color Spray
1 Sleep
2 Barkskin
2 Enhance Ability
2 Enthrall
2 Find Steed
2 Prayer of Healing
2 Ray of Enfeeblement
3 Conjure Animals
3 Counterspell
4 Conjure Minor Elementals
4 Conjure Woodland Beings
4 Giant Insect
4 Grasping Vine
5 Animate Objects
5 Conjure Elemental
5 Contagion
6 Conjure Fey
7 Conjure Celestial
8 Befuddlement

Revised Spells
Here is the list of all the "Revised" spells, with level:

0 Acid Splash
0 Dancing Lights
0 Light
0 Poison Spray
0 Produce Flame
0 Shillelagh
0 Shocking Grasp
0 Spare the Dying
0 Thaumaturgy
0 Vicious Mockery
1 Animal Friendship
1 Bless
1 Command
1 Compelled Duel
1 Comprehend Languages
1 Cure Wounds
1 Dissonant Whispers
1 Divine Favor
1 Ensnaring Strike
1 False Life
1 Find Familiar
1 Goodberry
1 Hail of Thorns
1 Healing Word
1 Hex
1 Hunter’s Mark
1 Inflict Wounds
1 Jump
1 Ray of Sickness
1 Searing Smite
1 Speak with Animals
1 Tasha’s Hideous Laughter
1 Thunderous Smite
1 Witch Bolt
1 Wrathful Smite
2 Alter Self
2 Animal Messenger
2 Arcane Lock
2 Augury
2 Beast Sense
2 Blindness/Deafness
2 Calm Emotions
2 Cloud of Daggers
2 Cordon of Arrows
2 Darkvision
2 Detect Thoughts
2 Enlarge/Reduce
2 Flame Blade
2 Gust of Wind
2 Lesser Restoration
2 Magic Weapon
2 Mirror Image
2 Moonbeam
2 Phantasmal Force
2 Shatter
2 Shining Smite
2 Spider Climb
2 Spike Growth
2 Spiritual Weapon
2 Suggestion
3 Aura of Vitality
3 Bestow Curse
3 Blinding Smite
3 Call Lightning
3 Clairvoyance
3 Conjure Barrage
3 Crusader’s Mantle
3 Daylight
3 Fly
3 Gaseous Form
3 Haste
3 Hunger of Hadar
3 Leomund’s Tiny Hut
3 Lightning Arrow
3 Major Image
3 Mass Healing Word
3 Meld into Stone
3 Sending
3 Sleet Storm
3 Slow
3 Speak with Plants
3 Stinking Cloud
3 Tongues
3 Water Walk
3 Wind Wall
4 Arcane Eye
4 Banishment
4 Blight
4 Compulsion
4 Confusion
4 Dimension Door
4 Divination
4 Dominate Beast
4 Evard’s Black Tentacles
4 Ice Storm
4 Leomund’s Secret Chest
4 Locate Creature
4 Mordenkainen’s Faithful Hound
4 Phantasmal Killer
4 Polymorph
4 Staggering Smite
4 Stoneskin
5 Banishing Smite
5 Bigby’s Hand
5 Conjure Volley
5 Contact Other Plane
5 Dispel Evil and Good
5 Dominate Person
5 Dream
5 Flame Strike
5 Hold Monster
5 Mass Cure Wounds
5 Mislead
5 Rary’s Telepathic Bond
5 Reincarnate
5 Swift Quiver
5 Telekinesis
5 Wall of Stone
6 Blade Barrier
6 Circle of Death
6 Contingency
6 Eyebite
6 Flesh to Stone
6 Globe of Invulnerability
6 Guards and Wards
6 Harm
6 Heal
6 Heroes’ Feast
6 Mass Suggestion
6 Otiluke’s Freezing Sphere
6 Otto's Irresistible Dance
6 Planar Ally
6 Sunbeam
6 Transport Via Plants
6 Wall of Ice
6 Wind Walk
7 Forcecage
7 Mordenkainen’s Sword
7 Plane Shift
7 Prismatic Spray
7 Project Image
7 Simulacrum
7 Symbol
7 Teleport
8 Animal Shapes
8 Antipathy/Sympathy
8 Demiplane
8 Dominate Monster
8 Earthquake
8 Holy Aura
8 Power Word Stun
8 Tsunami
9 Imprisonment
9 Mass Heal
9 Power Word Heal
9 Power Word Kill
9 Prismatic Wall
9 Shapechange
9 Storm of Vengeance
9 True Polymorph
9 Weird
9 Wish

